# JavaFX concurrent task setting state

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, javafx-2, javafx

I am creating the UI for my application which shares a core module with versions for other platforms. In JavaFX, I'm trying to use [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)s to do things in the background, but I can't figure out how to update the Task state.

This is what I'm trying to do. The `user` variable holds an instance of a class which performs [xmlrpc](/questions/tagged/xmlrpc) requests:

```
public Task<Integer> doLogin()
{
    return new Task<Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Integer call()
        {
            user.login();
            if (!user.getIsAuthorized())
            {
                // set the state to FAILED
            }
            else
            {
                // set the state to SUCCEDED
            }
            user.remember();
        }
    };

}
```

In my UI Thread I want to be able to do something like this to update my graph UI:

```
loginTask.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                // perform an UI update here depending on the state t
            }
        });
```

How am I supposed to set the state? There is nothing that does that in the [Task API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Task` states are not intended to be used for user logic. They are introduced to control `Task` flow. To add user logic into `Task` you need to use `result` conception. In your case you may want to use `Task<Boolean>` and result of your task will be `TRUE` for correct credentials and `FALSE` for incorrect:

Task creation:

```
public Task<Boolean> doLogin() {
    return new Task<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean call() {
            Boolean result = null;
            user.login();
            if (!user.getIsAuthorized()) {
                result = Boolean.FALSE;
            } else {
                result = Boolean.TRUE;
            }
            user.remember();
            return result;
        }
    };
}
```

Starting that task:

```
final Task<Boolean> login = doLogin();
login.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
        // This handler will be called if Task succesfully executed login code
        // disregarding result of login operation

        // and here we act according to result of login code
        if (login.getValue()) {
            System.out.println("Successful login");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid login");
        }

    }
});
login.setOnFailed(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
        // This handler will be called if exception occured during your task execution
        // E.g. network or db connection exceptions
        System.out.println("Connection error.");
    }
});
new Thread(login).start();
```