# ObservableList with extra elements in tableview

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

I am facing an issue with `ObservableList`. What I am doing is, adding an element to `ObservableList` and then setting it to `TableView` but the issue is whenever I am adding an element to `ObservableList` using `addAll()` some extra elements are shown in `TableView`.

Here is my code snippet

```
public void startRun(final TestCase test) {
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    if (sessionConfig.isEnableSessionControl() || detailscol.isVisible() == false)
        saveReportBtn.setDisable(true);
    else
        saveReportBtn.setDisable(true);
    testCaseList.add(test);
    start = "Running";
    removerow++;
    startRunDataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new TestExecutionTable(test.getName(), start));
    updatedDataStartrun.addAll(startRunDataList);

    testExecutioTable.setItems(updatedDataStartrun);
    lastOne = startRunDataList.get(0);
   }
});
t.start();
}
```

where `testCaseList = new ArrayList<TestCase>();
startRunDataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
updatedDataStartrun= FXCollections.observableArrayList();` 
are initialiazed at beggining of class.

above method `startRun(final TestCase test)` is being called in the loop.

```
for (TestCase test : tests) {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        listener.startSuite(null);

        listener.startRun(test);

        try {
            test.run(context, listener);
            listener.passed(test, latch);
        } catch (TestFailure failure) {
            listener.failed(test, failure, latch);
            //latch.wait();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            listener.error(test, t, latch);
            //latch.wait();
        } finally {
            listener.endRun(test);
        }
    }
```

However, the above code is working fine with Java 7 but not on the later version (Java 8 onwards).

Comment: You're modifying the GUI from a background thread.The results of doing this are unreliable and may even break the GUI in some cases.**Do not modify the gui from a background thread.**Potentially sharing the field values between threads makes things worse.The same values be added multiple times, since between assigning the`startRunDataList`and using`addAll`the list could be replaced with an assignment done by another thread.Furthermore creating a`ObservableList`containing a single element just to add it to another list is absolutely unnecessary.Just use the`add`method of that list.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. ill try the same

Answer (score 0):

You are running parallelizable code (code that works in separate threads) without any sort of synchronization. As such, the various threads can intertwine with each other in completely arbitrary ways. It might be the case that Java 7 used a different scheduling mechanism, which caused your code to accidentally work correctly.

If you ever have a situation where different threads might be accessing a collection in parallel, you might want to wrap fragment of code in `synchronized` blocks to ensure that the given code fragment is executed atomically without any interference from other threads.

Comment: while debugging what I observed when I am calling `t.start()`. it doesn't call `run()` immediately and it continues further execution.

Comment: ill try adding the synchronized block, let see how it works.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. What `Thread::start()` does is it **queues** the relevant thread for execution. When it is **actually** executed depends on the scheduler. 

You might want to look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: I would suggest you move away from handling the `addAll` part inside the thread altogether. Use a `Task` to gather the data you need. Return that data in the `Task` `setOnSucceeded` and at that point use the `addAll()` to update your observable list.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935366/javafx-concurrent-task-setting-state